# Pipeline log message and test-task

Tags: scala, sbt

Having `test task` defined as follows

```
lazy val UnitTest = config("unit").extend(Test)

Project("my-project", file("."))

testOptions in UnitTest := Seq(
    Tests.Argument("-h", "target/test-html"),
    Tests.Argument("-u", "target/test-xml"),
    Tests.Argument("-C", "SlowestTestReporter"),
    Tests.Argument("-oD"),
    Tests.Filter(testName => !testName.endsWith("Prop") && !testName.contains("Integration"))
)
```

Somebody please explain me why test-task override prints test output in first, and only after message `"=== Unit Tests ==="`

```
test in Test := {
  streams.value.log("=== Unit Tests ===")
  (test in UnitTest).value
}
```

And if I redefine test as follows then everything works as expected

```
test in Test := (test in UnitTest).dependsOn(unitTestsWelcome).value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.value defines a dependency.  All dependencies are computed prior to your task, not inline.  See sbt-sequential if you'd like sequential semantics on task dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

See [Execution semantics of tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Custom-Settings.html#Execution+semantics+of+tasks).

> Unlike plain Scala method calls, invoking `value` method on tasks will not be evaluated strictly. Instead, they simply act as placeholders to denote that `sampleIntTask` depends on `startServer` and `stopServer` tasks.